# How to click button to go to new page using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I push to go to the next page on Flutter? I got an error show I don't know why I can fix it anyone can help?

```
Widget signInBT() {
  return OutlineButton(
    child: Text(
       'Sign In',
       style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 16.0,
       color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {

      MaterialPageRoute materialPageRoute = new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: ( context) => Register(),
     );
     Navigator.of(context).push(materialPageRoute);   // error on of(context)
   },
  ); 
 }
```

Comment: how can i push for go to next page on flutter. I got an error show i don't know why i can fixed it anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

in your signInBT widget receive the BuildContext like signInBT(BuildContext context) and pass the context from where you are calling this signInBT widget. You are getting this error because this does not have the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  const Button({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(),
      onTap: () => signInBT(context),
    );
  }
}

Widget signInBT(BuildContext context) {
  return OutlineButton(
    child: Text(
      'Sign In',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      MaterialPageRoute materialPageRoute = new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Register(),
      );
      Navigator.of(context).push(materialPageRoute); // error on of(context)
    },
  );
}

class Register extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
  }
}
```

hope this is fixed your problem!